# ActiveAdmin model with has_many relationship - custom form button to "Add All" possible resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Example models:

```
class Person
  has_many :auto_mappings, dependent: :destroy
```

```
class Vehicle
  has_many :auto_mappings
```

```
class AutoMapping
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :vehicle

  validates :person,
            :vehicle,
            :usage,
            presence: true
```

In my ActiveAdmin form for Create/Edit on `Person`, I include an input `f.has_many` for the nested `AutoMapping` resource to add a single `AutoMapping` at a time, which works great. What I would like to accomplish is to somehow add a button that would add an `AutoMapping` for each `Vehicle` to the `Person`.

Is there an approach to accomplish this or is there another direction I should go?

Example AA form for `Person`:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :name
    f.input :age
    f.has_many :auto_mappings, class: 'auto_mapping' do |item|
      item.input :vehicle, include_blank: false, input_html: {class: "vehicle", disabled: item.object.persisted?}
      item.input :usage,
                 as: :select,
                 collection: %w[drive ride both]
                 include_blank: false
    end
  end
  # Maybe a custom member action to "Create Person with all Auto Mappings"?
  # I would prefer to auto populate the form page with `AutoMappings` rather than create them all on Submit if possible.
  f.actions
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if I should provide more detail or what I want to accomplish is not clear.

Comment: I was able to add an action button to "Create (or Update) Person with all Auto Mappings" easily but I would still prefer to populate the form rather than submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to extend has_many.es6 to make an Ajax call and add the items.